# what is the hook name in order to alter theme function of specific element

Tags: theming

imagine that we have a list if items in $items array that it's theme function is list_item in specific page.

code is

```
theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
```

but in my module, I want to alter the parameter 'item_list' and I want to use my custom render function 'custom_item_list'

I know that I must register and define custom_item_list function but I don't know in what hook I am able to alter the theme_function parameter of specific element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_theme() function to use custom item list.

Hook theme:

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
  if ($type == 'module')
  {
    return array(
      'custom_item_list' => array(
        'variables' => array('var_name'=>NULL),
        'template' => 'custom-item-list',
      ),
    );
  }
  return array(); //will raise fatal error if void
}
```

Call it as usual:

```
theme('custom_item_list', array('var_name' => mymodule_variable()));
```

Comment: I agree with your idea. but as I wrote in my question, I have defined my custom theme function but I don't know in which hook I can change the theme function of specific element. for example a block that is created by another module makes list items that is rendered by item_list, now I want to alter this list and render it by my custom theme function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7.x) which is the hook modules can use to alter a theme function implemented by other modules. `hook_theme()` is for theme functions your module defines itself.

Just set `$theme_registry['item_list']['function']` to `'theme_custom_item_list'`, and `theme_custom_item_list()` will be called instead of `theme_item_list()`.
Keep in mind that, if you need to alter the content of the `$variables` parameter passed to a theme function, and not its output, you can implement `hook_preprocess_item_list()`, since every theme function has its own preprocess functions.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_item_list(&$variables) {
  // Change the title for the list.
  $variables['title'] = 'My own list title';
}
```

Comment: but if I alter $theme_registry['item_list'] function , all element that are themed by item_list will be affected. I want to define a new custom theme and set the theme function of specific item, not alter the body of item_list theme function.

Comment: If the theme function is only used by your module, then just implement `hook_theme()` to create a new theme function your module will call with (for example) `theme('custom_item_list', $variables)`. if you want to use a new theme function that is used from every module on specific pages, that is a little more harder to implement.

Comment: i want to know, If I want to set a new theme_function wrapper for specific element, in which hook I am able to do that before the element rendering.